# When was the threading implemented in unix?

Tags: linux, history, multithreading

Which is the first Unix version or Linux version which implemented threads. And in which version bound and unbound threads were implemented? I know that in current Linux version threads are unbound by default. But is there any version of Unix or Linux in which threads are bound by default instead of unbound. If some one can give a link to a complete change-log of Unix versions that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel 2.0 had LinuxThreads. I think this was new to 2.0 and not present in the previous 1.3 kernel.

Comment: But there were no threads as POSIX threads are now. In fact, they were processes sharing their memory. For example, each thread of a process had a different PID in LinuxThreands.

Comment: AFAIK Linux implements threads as processes internally till today (with some modifications like the same address space of course).

Answer (score 0):

Solaris 2.2 (released May 1993) is apparently the first, per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(operating_system)#Version_history).